# Google Maps Heatmap in Websharper?

Tags: google-maps, f#, websharper

I'm evaluating Websharper, and the project I'm doing is all about heat maps in Google Maps. 
Is it possible to use the Google Maps extension for Websharper to display heatmaps? 
I'm not using Fusion tables. 
There is hardly any documentation available, but through browsing `IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Maps` in intellisense it doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the latest [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/WebSharper.Google.Maps/2.4.52.144). I have not yet been able to finish the upgrade yet, but this binary will give you just enough to get started with Heatmaps API. For example, see [this](https://github.com/intellifactory/WebSharper.Google.Maps/blob/master/if-ws-google-maps-tests/HeatMaps.fs). The Google Maps extension is now open-source with matching Bitbucket and GitHub repositories, contributions are very welcome.

Comment: Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#HeatmapLayer I'm trying to do something similar to this, you can view source there: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4117548/heatmap.html

Comment: The app looks very nice. I am sorry for the delay, I will try to get back to you as soon as possible - added the bug 115 (http://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/115/). I think we will certainly fix it by the end of the week, hopefully sooner.

Comment: Cool that you've open-sourced it. Clearly the correct thing to do. My question raises a bigger concern with Websharper: The helplessness when I want to do something you haven't thought of. Open-sourcing cleanly fixes this. Unfortunately, I've delivered the project I was considering Websharper for today, and a rewrite does not make sense.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I guess technically you could still have went ahead with `[<Inline "foo">]` if the extension was closed. But I hear you. Just keep an eye on WebSharper, we are working hard to make things better and more transparent.